# Get SSIS solution from VSS

Tags: ssis, visual-sourcesafe

I have very little idea on SSIS and controlling this using VSS (Visual Source Safe). I have a requirement in my project to go through a few SSIS solutions/Projects. Can someone please help me how can I access this and view as a proper setup. Below is the rough structure of the VSS

Project1

-Project1 : has file.sql, Project1.sln, Project1.vssscc (please help me understand this)

```
-dbBuild : has db_build.dbp, db_build dbp.vspscc

-dbStaging
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would open VSS and navigate to the Project folder.  Then I would right-click the Project folder and choose Get Latest Version.

You will be prompted to set the Working folder - I normally create a new folder on the Dev machine's hard drive e.g. C:\Dev\MyProject.  I would check the options for Recursive and then Build tree.

This will effectively create a copy of the latest VSS content in the hard drive folder, which you can then open using Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Working perfectly. But whenever I open this using VS 2008, the files and project gets checked out from vss. Why is that? Even when the solution is checked out by some one, it will replace me and check out in my name. I just want a copy of entire project and no link to VSS. I want to test some logic and I dont want it to be saved on vss. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I would "Unbind" the Project from VSS. Use File / Source Control / Change Source Control, select the solution and all the project files, and choose Unbind.